# Is there an equivalent of SSH agent forwarding for curl's .netrc?

Tags: curl, ssh-agent, .netrc

I know they're very different different things but is there anything similar to ssh's agent forwarding for the `.netrc` file? i.e. I want my local .netrc file to be available when I ssh into a remote machine and run `curl`, but I don't want to copy the sensitive content of that file to the remote machine.